# ClassCastException when intercept Parcelable with inheritance

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am working in Android Studio and any time I need `Parcelable` just auto generate the code. My scenario is that i have super class `A` and class `B` extended from class `A`. I'd like to pass through an intent class `B` but when I intercept it I get  an error sayng `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: pack.A cannot be cast to pack.B`. The code is:

```
public class A implements Parcelable {

    private String str1;

    protected A(Parcel in) {
        str1 = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str1);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<A> CREATOR = new Creator<A>() {
        @Override
        public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new A(in);
        }

        @Override
        public A[] newArray(int size) {
            return new A[size];
        }
    };
}

public class B extends A {

    private String str2;

    protected B(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }
}
```

I'm confused about this error. Any help is apreciated

Comment: your B class needs at least the Creator, to know how to create an instance of B.

Comment: Your class B is missing `Creator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following scenario(using the same classes, a is super, b is child):

You can do:

```
A a = new B();
```

But you cannot do:

```
B b = new A();
```

When you load the parcelable for B, but the type is A, you basically do this(in different code, but what you basically tell the machine is):

```
B b = new A()
```

Meaning you cannot do this as you intend per now. YOu have to create a custom creator for B, where you create a parcelable with type B.

As for the error, it is because the creator is of type A, but you cast it to B. Which is the same as `B b = new A()`. So in order to resolve it you have to create a creator for B.

---

Inheritance is a somewhat complicated topic, as there is a lot to keep track of in terms of what can be cast where.

Answer (score 1):

As @njzk2 said, you need to declare a new `CREATOR` in class B:

```
public class B extends A {

    private String str2;

    protected B(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        str2 = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeString(str2);
    }

    public static final Creator<B> CREATOR = new Creator<B>() {
        @Override
        public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new B(in);
        }

        @Override
        public B[] newArray(int size) {
            return new B[size];
        }
    };
}
```